# Generator not working to split string by particular identifier . Python 2

Tags: python, string, split, generator, yield

So far I have found a way to yield the name, string, and extra string.  It works for the second one but does not work for the first one? it's so weird because the formats are really similar. is it because it's multiple lines? i thought the `if line == '+': pass` would bypass the issue.

i added in the print '\n' to show the difference

Input:

```
@first_name
AlongStringOfText
ThatHasNoSpaces
ButIsSeparatedByLineBreaks
+
{+iuhsfIUHSDFUi8849308989829
0990+-]@@@#*$()(@*$*)))***)@@**@#*u
sdfiuhnknwuiewi
+
@second_name
MoreTextThatCouldBeOnOneLine
+
+{~~~(@#UhuisdfiuhIUHDSFIUFHIl)}9823)88hafff
#empty line at end
```

Current Script:

```
def organize(input_file):
    name = None
    body = ''
    extra = ''
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('@'):
            if name: 
                yield name, body, extra
                body = ''
                extra = ''
            name = line
        else:
            body = body + line
            if line == '+':
                pass
    print '\n'
    body,extra = body.split('+',1)

    yield name,body,extra

for line in organize(file_path):
    print line
```

Output:

```
('@first_name', 'AlongStringOfTextThatHasNoSpacesButIsSeparatedByLineBreaks+{+iuhsfIUHSDFUi88493089898290990+-]@@@#*$()(@*$*)))***)@@**@#*usdfiuhnknwuiewi+', '')


('@second_name', 'MoreTextThatCouldBeOnOneLine', '+{~~~(@#UhuisdfiuhIUHDSFIUFHIl)}9823)88hafff')
```

Desired Output:

```
('@first_name','AlongStringOfTextThatHasNoSpacesButIsSeparatedByLineBreaks','{+iuhsfIUHSDFUi88493089898290990+-]@@@#*$()(@*$*)))***)@@**@#*usdfiuhnknwuiewi')
('@second_name','MoreTextThatCouldBeOnOneLine','+{~~~(@#UhuisdfiuhIUHDSFIUFHIl)}9823)88hafff')
```

Comment: If you change the first `yield` to `yield name, body` (removing `extra`, it seems to do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is, you are not `split`ing before yielding. So change the code like this

```
    if line.startswith('@'):
        if name: 
            body, extra = body.split('+',1)
            yield name, body, extra
            body = ''
        name = line
    else:
        body = body + line
body, extra = body.split('+',1)
yield name, body, extra
```

Also, the following `if` condition has no effect in the output of the program

```
if line == '+':
    pass
```

So, I removed it in the above code.

Comment: i'm having a problem with this . . . when there is a '@' as the first character on a non-name line and non-+ line