# Parsing with multiple identifiers

Tags: python, parsing, generator

I was trying to implement this block of code from [Generator not working to split string by particular identifier . Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351451/generator-not-working-to-split-string-by-particular-identifier-python-2) but I found two bugs in it that I can’t seem to fix.

```
Input:
@m120204
CTCT
+
~@@!
@this_one_has_an_at_sign
CTCTCT
+
@jfik9
@thisoneisempty

+


#empty line after + and then empty line to end file (2 empty lines)
```

The two bugs are:
    (i) when there is a @ that starts the line of code after the ‘+’ line such as the 2nd entry (@this_one_has_an_at_sign)
    (ii) when there line following the @identification_line or the line following the ‘+’ lines are empty like in 3rd entry (@thisoneisempty)

I would like the output to be the same as the post that i referenced:

```
yield (name, body, extra)
```

in the case of @this_one_has_an_at_sign

```
name= this_one_has_an_at_sign 
body= CTCTCT
quality= @jfik9
```

in the case of @thisoneisempty

```
name= thisoneisempty
body= ''
quality= ''
```

I tried using flags but i can’t seem to fix this issue.  I know how to do it without using a generator but i’m going to be using big files so i don’t want to go down that path. My current code is:

```
def organize(input_file):
    name = None
    body = ''
    extra = ''
    for line in input_file:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith('@'):
            if name:
                body, extra = body.split('+',1)
                yield name, body, extra
                body = ''
            name = line
        else:
            body = body + line
    body, extra = body.split('+',1)
    yield name, body, extra

for line in organize(file_path):
    print line
```

Comment: What's the desired and actual output here?

Comment: i've added the output.  it is the same exact format as the question i have referenced but i found 2 bugs that i mentioned above