# Fastq parser not taking empty sequence (and other edge cases). Python

Tags: python, parsing, generator, bioinformatics, string

this is a continuation of [Generator not working to split string by particular identifier . Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26351451/generator-not-working-to-split-string-by-particular-identifier-python-2) . however, i modified the code completely and it's not the same format at all.  this is about edge cases

```
Edge Cases:
 . when sequence length is different than number of quality values
 . when there's an empty sequence or entry
 . when the number of lines with quality values is more than one
```

i cannot figure out how to work with the edge cases above.  If its an empty data file, then I still want to output empty strings.  i'm trying with these sequences right here for my input file: (Just a little background, IDs are set by @ at beginning of line, sequence characters are followed by the lines after until a line with + is reached.  the next lines are going to have quality values (value ~= chr(char) ) this format is terrible and poorly thought out.

```
@m120204_092117_richard_c100250832550000001523001204251233_s1_p0/422/ccs
CTGTTGCGGATTGTTTGGCTATGGCTAAAACCGATGAAGAAAAAGGAAATGCCAAAACCGTTTATAGCGATTGATCCAAGAAATCCAAAATAAAAGGACACAAAACAAACAAAATCAATTGAGTAAAACAGAAAGGCCATCAAGCAAGCGAGTGCTTGATAACTTAGATGACCCTACTGATCAAGAGGCCATAGAGCAATGTTTAGAGGGCTTGAGCGATAGTGAAAGGGCGCTAATTCTAGGAATTCAAACGACAAGCTGATGAAGTGGATCTGATTTATAGCGATCTAAGAAACCGTAAAACCTTTGATAACATGGCGGCTAAAGGTTATCCGTTGTTACCAATGGATTTCAAAAATGGCGGCGATATTGCCACTATTAACCGCTACTAATGTTGATGCGGACAAATAGCTAGCAGATAATCCTATTTATGCTTCCATAGAGCCTGATATTACCAAGCATACGAAACAGAAAAAACCATTAAGGATAAGAATTTAGAAGCTAAATTGGCTAAGGCTTTAGGTGGCAATAAACAAATGACGATAAAGAAAAAAGTAAAAAACCCACAGCAGAAACTAAAGCAGAAAGCAATAAGATAGACAAAGATGTCGCAGAAACTGCCAAAAATATCAGCGAAATCGCTCTTAAGAACAAAAAAGAAAAGAGTGGGATTTTGTAGATGAAAATGGTAATCCCATTGATGATAAAAAGAAAGAAGAAAAACAAGATGAAACAAGCCCTGTCAAACAGGCCTTTATAGGCAAGAGTGATCCCACATTTGTTTTTAGCGCAATACACCCCCATTGAAATCACTCTGACTTCTAAAGTAGATGCCACTCTCACAGGTATAGTGAGTGGGGTTGTAGCCAAAGATGTATGGAACATGAACGGCACTATGATCTTATTAAGACAAACGGCCACTAAGGTGTATGGGAATTATCAAAGCGTGAAAGGTGGCCACGCCTATTATGACTCGTTTAATGATAGTCTTTACTAAAGCCATTACGCCTGATGGGGTGGTGATACCTCTAGCAAACGCTCAAGCAGCAGGCATGCTGGGTGAAGCAGGCGGTAGATGGCTATGTGAATAATCACTTCATGAAGCGTATAGGCTTTGCTGTGATAGCAAGCGTGGTTAATAGCTTCTTGCAAACTGCACCTATCATAGCTCTAGATAAACTCATAGGCCTTGGCAAAGGCAGAAGTGAAAGGACACCTGAATTTAATTACGCTTTGGGTCAAGCTATCAATGGTAGTATGCAAAGTTCAGCTCAGATGTCTAATCAAATTCTAGGGCAACTGATGAATATCCCCCAAGTTTTTACAAAAATGAGGGCGATAGTATTAAGATTCTCACCATGGACGATATTGATTTTAGTGGTGTGTATGATGTTAAAATTGACCAACAAATCTGTGGTAGATGAAATTATCAAACAAAGCACCAAAAACTTTGTCTAGAGAACATGAAGAAATCACCACAGCCCCAAAGGTGGCAATTGATTCAAGAGAAAGGATAAAATATATTCATGTTATTAAACTCGGTTCTTTACAAAATAAAAAGACAAACCAACCTAGGCTCTTCTAGAGGA
+
J(78=AEEC65HR+++*3327H00GD++++FF440.+-64444426ABAB<:=7888((/788P>>LAA8*+')3&++=<////==<4&<>EFHGGIJ66P;;;9;;FE34KHKHP<<11;HK:57678NJ990((&26>PDDJE,,JL>=@@88,8,+>::J88ELF9.-5.45G+@@@NP==??<>455F((<BB===;;EE;3><<;M=>89PLLPP?>KP8+7699>A;ANO===J@'''B;.(...HP?E@@AHGE77MNOO9=OO?>98?DLIMPOG>;=PRKB5H---3;MN&&&&&F?B>;99;8AA53)A<=;>777:<>;;8:LM==))6:@K..M?6?::7,/4444=JK>>HNN=//16@--F@K;9<:6449@BADD;>CD11JE55K;;;=&&%%,3644DL&=:<877..3>344:>>?44*+MN66PG==:;;?0./AGLKF99&&5?>+++JOP333333AC@EBBFBCJ>>HINPMNNCC>>++6:??3344>B=<89:/000::K>A=00@,+-/.,#(LL@>@I555K22221115666666477KML559-,333?GGGKCCP:::PPNPPNP??PPPLLMNOKKFOP2Q&&P7777PM<<<=<6<HPOPPP44?=@=:?BB=89:<<DHI777777645545PPO((((((((C3P??PM0000@NOPJPPFGGL<<<NNGNKGGGGGEELKB'''(((((L===L<<..*--MJ111?PO=788<8GG>>?JJL88,,1CF))??=?M6667PPKAKM&&&&&<?P43?OENPP''''&5579ICIFRPPPPOP>:>>>P888PLPAJDPCCDMMD;9=FBADDJFD7;ALL?,,,,06ID13..000DA4CFJC44,,->ED99;44CJK?42FAB?=CLNO''PJI999&77&&ERP><)))O==D677FP768PA=@@HEE.::NM&&&>O''PO88H@A999P<:?IHL;;;GIIPPMMPPB7777PP>>>>KOPIIEEE<<CL%%5656AAAG<<DDFFGG%%N21778;M&&>>CCL::LKK6.711DGHHMIA@BAJ7>%6700;;=@@?=;J55>>QP<<:>MF;;RPL==JMMPPPQR@@P===;=BM99M>>PPOQGD44777PKKFP=<'''2215566>CG>>HH<<PLJI800CE<<PPPMGNOPMJ>>GG***LCCC777,,@AP>>AOPMFN99ENNMEPP>>>>>>CLPP??66OOKLLP=:>>KMBCPOPP@FKEI<<ML?>EAF>>>LDCD77JK=H>BN==:=<<<:==JN,,,659???8K<:==<4))))))P98>>>>;967777N66@@@AMKKKIKPMG;;AD88HN&&LMIGJOJMGHPC>@5D((((C?9--?8HGCDPNH7?9974;;AC&ABH''#%:=NP:,,9999=GJG>>=>JG21''':9>>>;;MP*****OKKKIE??55PPKJ21:K---///Q11//EN&';;;;:=;00011;IP@@PP11?778JDDMM>>::KKLLKLNONOHDMPKLMIB>>?JP>9;KJL====;8;;;L)))))E@=$$$#.::,,BPJK76B;;F5<<J::K
@m120204_092117_richard_c100250832550000001523001204251233_s1_p0/904/ccs
CTCTCTCATCACACACGAGGAGTGAAGAGAGAACCTCCTCTCCACACGTGGAGTGAGGAGATCCTCTCACACACGTGAGGTGTTGAGAGAGATACTCTCTCATCACCTCACGTGAGGAGTGAGAGAGAT
+
{~~~~~sXNL>>||~~fVM~jtu~&&(uxy~f8YHh=<gA5
''<O1A44N'`oK57(((G&&Q*Q66;"$$Df66E~Z\ZMO>^;%L}~~~~~Q.~~~~x~@-LF9>~MMqbV~ABBV=99mhIwGRR~
@different_number_of_seq_qual
ATCG
+
**!
@this_should_work
GGGG
+
****
```

The ones with an error, I'm trying to replace the seq and qual strings with empty strings

```
seq,qual = '',''
```

Here's my code so far.  These edge cases are so difficult for me to figure out please help . . .

```
def read_fastq(input, offset):
    """
    Inputs a fastq file and reads each line at a time.  'offset' parameter can be set to 33 (phred+33 encoding 
    fastq), and 64.  Yields a tuple in the format (ID, comments for a sequence, sequence, [integer quality values])
    Capable of reading empty sequences and empty files. 
    """

    ID, comment, seq, qual = None,'','',''

    step = 1 #step is a variable that organizes the order fastq parsing
    #step= 1 scans for ID and comment line
    #step= 2 adds relevant lines to sequence string
    #step= 3 adds quality values to string
    for line in input:
        line = line.strip()
        if step == 1 and line.startswith('@'): #Step system from Nedda Saremi
            if ID is not None: 
                qual = [ord(char)-offset for char in qual] #Converts from phred encoding to integer values
                sep = None
                if ' ' in ID: sep = ' '
                if sep is not None: 
                    ID, comment =  ID.split(sep,1) #Separates ID and comment by  ' '

                yield ID, comment, seq, qual
                ID,comment,seq,qual = None,'','','' #Resets variable for next sequence
            ID = line[1:]
            step = 2
            continue
        if step==2 and not line.startswith('@') and not line.startswith('+'):
            seq = seq + line.strip()
            continue
        if step == 2 and line.startswith('+'):
            step = 3
            continue
        while step == 3: 
        #process the quality data
            if len(qual) == len(seq):
            #once the length of the quality seq and seq are the same, end gathering data
                step = 1
                continue
            if len(qual) < len(seq):
                qual = qual + line.strip()
                if len(qual) < len(seq): 
                    step = 3
                    continue
                if (len(qual) > len(seq)): 
                    sys.stderr.write('\nError: ' + ID + ' sequence length not equal to quality values\n')
                    comment,seq,qual= '','',''
                    ID = line
                    step = 1
                    continue
            break

    if ID is not None:
        #Section reserved for last entry in file
        if len(qual) > 0: 
            qual = [ord(char)-offset for char in qual]
        sep = None
        if ' ' in ID: sep = ' '
        if sep is not None: 
            ID, comment =  ID.split(sep,1)
        if len(seq) == 0: ID,comment,seq,qual= '','','',''
        yield ID, comment, seq, qual
```

my output is skipping the ID @m120204_092117_richard_c100250832550000001523001204251233_s1_p0/904/ccs and adding @**! when it should not be in the output

```
@m120204_092117_richard_c100250832550000001523001204251233_s1_p0/422/ccs
CTGTTGCGGATTGTTTGGCTATGGCTAAAACCGATGAAGAAAAAGGAAATGCCAAAACCGTTTATAGCGATTGATCCAAGAAATCCAAAATAAAAGGACACAAAACAAACAAAATCAATTGAGTAAAACAGAAAGGCCATCAAGCAAGCGAGTGCTTGATAACTTAGATGACCCTACTGATCAAGAGGCCATAGAGCAATGTTTAGAGGGCTTGAGCGATAGTGAAAGGGCGCTAATTCTAGGAATTCAAACGACAAGCTGATGAAGTGGATCTGATTTATAGCGATCTAAGAAACCGTAAAACCTTTGATAACATGGCGGCTAAAGGTTATCCGTTGTTACCAATGGATTTCAAAAATGGCGGCGATATTGCCACTATTAACCGCTACTAATGTTGATGCGGACAAATAGCTAGCAGATAATCCTATTTATGCTTCCATAGAGCCTGATATTACCAAGCATACGAAACAGAAAAAACCATTAAGGATAAGAATTTAGAAGCTAAATTGGCTAAGGCTTTAGGTGGCAATAAACAAATGACGATAAAGAAAAAAGTAAAAAACCCACAGCAGAAACTAAAGCAGAAAGCAATAAGATAGACAAAGATGTCGCAGAAACTGCCAAAAATATCAGCGAAATCGCTCTTAAGAACAAAAAAGAAAAGAGTGGGATTTTGTAGATGAAAATGGTAATCCCATTGATGATAAAAAGAAAGAAGAAAAACAAGATGAAACAAGCCCTGTCAAACAGGCCTTTATAGGCAAGAGTGATCCCACATTTGTTTTTAGCGCAATACACCCCCATTGAAATCACTCTGACTTCTAAAGTAGATGCCACTCTCACAGGTATAGTGAGTGGGGTTGTAGCCAAAGATGTATGGAACATGAACGGCACTATGATCTTATTAAGACAAACGGCCACTAAGGTGTATGGGAATTATCAAAGCGTGAAAGGTGGCCACGCCTATTATGACTCGTTTAATGATAGTCTTTACTAAAGCCATTACGCCTGATGGGGTGGTGATACCTCTAGCAAACGCTCAAGCAGCAGGCATGCTGGGTGAAGCAGGCGGTAGATGGCTATGTGAATAATCACTTCATGAAGCGTATAGGCTTTGCTGTGATAGCAAGCGTGGTTAATAGCTTCTTGCAAACTGCACCTATCATAGCTCTAGATAAACTCATAGGCCTTGGCAAAGGCAGAAGTGAAAGGACACCTGAATTTAATTACGCTTTGGGTCAAGCTATCAATGGTAGTATGCAAAGTTCAGCTCAGATGTCTAATCAAATTCTAGGGCAACTGATGAATATCCCCCAAGTTTTTACAAAAATGAGGGCGATAGTATTAAGATTCTCACCATGGACGATATTGATTTTAGTGGTGTGTATGATGTTAAAATTGACCAACAAATCTGTGGTAGATGAAATTATCAAACAAAGCACCAAAAACTTTGTCTAGAGAACATGAAGAAATCACCACAGCCCCAAAGGTGGCAATTGATTCAAGAGAAAGGATAAAATATATTCATGTTATTAAACTCGGTTCTTTACAAAATAAAAAGACAAACCAACCTAGGCTCTTCTAGAGGA
+
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

Error: different_number_of_seq_qual sequence length not equal to quality values
@**!

+

@this_should_work
GGGG
+
****
```

Comment: I am confused by the need for this processing. A proper fastq file will have none of the three edge cases you have described. By definition the sequence and quality scores will be of equal length, and there will only be one line per sequence/qual score. Thus each read should be represented in 4 lines. Further more a read with no sequence shouldn't be there at all. If you are cleaning up old data or bad quality data then a script like this would be useful, but I would suggest looking at obtaining better quality data in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use BioPython.

Your bug appears to be the read that is skipped has 129 bases in its sequence but only 128 qv. So your parser reads the next defline as a quality line which then makes it too long so it prints the error.

Then your states don't account for the situation of where you are in `step 1` but dont see a defline. So you keep reading extra lines overwritting the `ID` variable.

but if you really want to write your own parser:

I'll address your questions one at a time.

**when sequence length is different than number of quality values**

This is invalid.  Each record in the fastq file must have the an equal number of bases and qualities. Different records in the file can be different lengths from each other, but each record must have equal bases and qualities.

**when there's an empty sequence or entry**
An empty read will have blank lines for the sequence and quality lines like this:

```
@SOLEXA1_0007:1:9:610:1983#GATCAG/2

+SOLEXA1_0007:1:9:610:1983#GATCAG/2

@SOLEXA1_0007:2:13:163:254#GATCAG/2
CGTAGTACGATATACGCGCGTGTACTGCTACGTCTCACTTTCGCAAGATTGCTCAGCTCATTGATGCTCAATGCTGGGCCATATCTCTTTTCTTTTTTTC
+SOLEXA1_0007:2:13:163:254#GATCAG/2
HHHHGHHEHHHHHE=HAHCEGEGHAG>CHH>EG5@>5*ECE+>AEEECGG72B&A*)569B+03B72>5.A>+*A>E+7A@G<CAD?@############
```

**when the number of lines with quality values is more than one**

Due to the requirements from the first answer above.  We know that the number of bases and qualities must match.  Also there will never be an `+` character in the sequence block. So we can keep parsing the sequence block until we see a line that starts with `+`.  Then we know we are done parsing sequence.  Then we can keep parsing quality lines until we get the same number of qualities as is in the sequence.  We can't rely on looking for any special characters because depending on the quality encoding, `@` could be a valid quality call.

Also as an aside, you appear to be splitting the sequence defline to parse out the optional comment.  You have to be careful for CASAVA 1.8 format which stupidly has spaces. So you might need a regex to see if it's a CASAVA 1.8 format then don't split on whitespace etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using one of the robust python packages that are available for dealing with this kind of data rather than writing a parser from scratch? In partincular I'd recommend checking out [HTSeq](http://www-huber.embl.de/users/anders/HTSeq/doc/overview.html)